# Oracle binding not showing in send port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a very simple BizTalk application that is polling the records from a SQL server and does some transformation then save it to the Oracle DB. I used BizTalk 2010, SQL server 2012, Oracle 11g each is hosted on their own separate server. BizTalk was setup properly and has been working fine.

[image]

I have attached the orchestration diagram for clarity. Nothing fancy, I have set up the sending and receiving port successfully (can connect to all the database, and I used typedpolling for inbound and insert operation for the outbound. The project can be compiled and deployed successfully.

I have imported the bindings to BizTalk Admin Console and can see both bindings on the receive port and send port. The following image shows the bindings for send port is there.

[image]

However, when I tried to configure the Orchestration, I can only see the receive Ports in the selection but the send ports information is not available for me to pick.

[image]

From my limited exposure to BizTalk in the past, I can select the send port once I have imported the bindings to the console. I wonder what I have done incorrectly this time?

Comment: Is the Send Port in the bindings a one way send, or is it Send & Receive?   If it is a Send & Receive then the port in your orchestration also needs to be a send and receive.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: The binding was done automatically by VS2010 when I added generated item and used Consume Adapter Service. I used OracleDBBinding and after entering my credentials, it was connected to the database. I selected Client (Outbound operations) for the contract type, picked the table on the Schema I wanted and selected Insert for categories and operations. So I believe it is only one way operation but I am not very well versed in BizTalk to make sure it was only one way and not both. How can I make sure it is one way as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a table operation such as an insert will be a request (the insert) and the response which shows it has succeeded (with an array/list of ID's of the new records).  If you look the port that was created from the bindings you will see both a Send pipeline and a Receive Pipeline.  Just make the port in the Orchestration a Request/Response, and consume the response (even if you don't do anything with it).  Then you can bind the logical port the the actual port one as the logical port will then match the port.

Comment: Ah..That makes sense. Please let me try it out again and will mark this as response after I am successful. But I understand your instruction... Many thanks!

Comment: Your instruction makes sense but I still can not make it to work as I run into another road block trying to implement your suggestion. You said the port needs to be bi-directional which makes sense, but that means I need to have another request to send the converted oracle records from the original sql record to the port for insertion. BizTalk is then complaining the "you must specify at least one already-initialized correlation set for a non-activation receive that is on a non-selfcorrelating port". How do I do that?

Comment: The logical send port saveOracleMsgPort should be bi-directional and there should be a send shape SaveRecords (as you have) and a receive shape after it connected too it.   Your first Receive shape getRecords should have Activate set to True.

Comment: Yes, and I had it the other way around and got the weird error msg. Rookie mistake.. On the similar note, do I really need an orchestration for this simple stuff? Can I just use the schema/bindings and get it done without orchestration? (assuming the mapping fields are identical)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do it without an Orchestration by having a the outbound map and the send port and a filter on the send port subscribing to the receive port. You would also have to have something subscribing to the response from the send port.  See this blog http://biztalk2010changes.blogspot.co.nz/2011/04/insert-update-delete-select-operation.html

Comment: Awesome... That is a great blog...thank you... I have a follow up question since is kinda related but if you want me to submit as a different question, I would too. When I tried to typedpolling the sql database, I got back a whole bunch of records and I want to debatch them. I managed to debatch them successfully by specifying the <schema> being an envelope and body xpath pointed to the individual record. What should I do on the insert side (outbound) for BizTalk to know my message has been debatched so that it will not error out on me?

Comment: That would be worth doing as a new question.